# Add the same idProduct to SESSION in cart php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, session, cart

I´m making a cart in php that get the data of the products from a MySQL Database.

The problem is: I can´t add the same product to the SESSION.

I need that, because the user may want one product with a picture and another one with another picture;

I need that so much.

This is the code I'm using to add the item to the cart:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){

     //ADD TO THE CART
     if($_GET['action'] == 'add'){
        $id = intval($_GET['idProduct']);
        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){
           $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = 1;
        }else{
           $_SESSION['cart'][$id] += 1;
        }
     }

//UPDATE CART
     if($_GET['action'] == 'up'){
        if(is_array($_POST['prod'])){
           foreach($_POST['prod'] as $id => $qtd){
              $id  = intval($id);
              $qtd = intval($qtd);
              if(!empty($qtd) || $qtd <> 0){
                 $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = $qtd;
              }else{
                 unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

I don't know how to add the same product.  I tried using an Array and getting the KEY from it, but I didn't know how to use it;

Comment: `can´t add the same product`? you want to add the product again, which is already in the cart?

Comment: yes, I want to add a product with the same ID, otherwise I have another SESSION to store image details according to the product. So, it may have different images with the same products

Comment: why don't you just update the quantity of already added product ?

Comment: Are you saying that something with a picture has the same productId as something without a picture?

Comment: because I need different images to the same kind of product. Imagine that I want a shirt (id = 1) with a blue picture, but I want a another shirt (id = 1) with a red picture. Than I need to add to the cart the item with the same ID

Comment: I have two kinds of products: not personalized and personalized. The personalized must have a picture, but the not personalized is just add to the cart

Comment: Why do they have the same productID?

Comment: Because it´s the same product, what is changed is the picture that the user will upload to it